# Msqli query array

Tags: php, loops, variables

So I have my code

```
    function GetApi($connection,$UserId){
        global $Apicall;
        $Apicall = array();
        $Apiidquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ID FROM ` Characterapi`  WHERE UserId = '$UserId'");
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Apiidquery)){
            $Apicall[] = $results['ID'];
        }
}
```

The output of this function if I call 
$Apicall[0] = 3
$Apicall[1] = 11
and this is the information I want. But now I want to use a function like

```
  function Keyquery($Apicall,$connection ){
    global $keyidcall, $keyid ,$Vcode;
    $Keyidquery = array();
    $Keyidquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT keyid, Vcode FROM `Characterapi` WHERE ID = '$Apicall'");
    $results = mysqli_fetch_object($Keyidquery);
    $keyid = $results->keyid;
    $Vcode = $results->Vcode;
}
```

This code does run if i set $Apicall ="3"; The issue im having is that I want the first function to get All the IDs associated with $userId in my data base then for each Id run the second function to to get the two specific pieces of information from that query.

Comment: Loop `$Apicall` and call `Keyquery()` with each value? You shouldn't really do this though, much better to retrieve all the information you want in one query then loop the results - i.e. `SELECT ... WHERE ID IN (" . implode(',', $Apicall) . ")`

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment below, this is the solution which I would use. **However** you should be wary of using this method as it does not parameterize the values, and as such not sanitized.

```
<?php

  function Keyquery($Apicall,$connection ){
    global $keyidcall, $keyid ,$Vcode;

    $string = "ID IN('";
    $string.= implode("','", $Apicall);
    $string.="')";

    $Keyidquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT keyid, Vcode FROM `Characterapi` WHERE ".$string.";");
    $results = mysqli_fetch_object($Keyidquery);
    $keyid = $results->keyid;
    $Vcode = $results->Vcode;
}

?>
```